# Should I use ANOVA OR ANCOVA?

Tags: anova

My research topic is "the impact of internal controls in an organisation". With this which one (ANOVA OR ANCOVA) would be best for my analysis looking at the research topic.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to determine the appropriate statistical method(s) for the problem. Please explain the research topic in more detail, along with what are the response and predictor variables.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be that if you only compare the average between two groups , you should use ANOVA. The ANCOVA is used when you have a co-variate.